# Highchart bubbles like with radius 1,2 look very small

Tags: highcharts

I have highchart bubble chart based on eg. http://www.highcharts.com/cases/bubble.htm
The radius for bubbles is set dynamically depending on a table's column value.
The value for that column ranges from 0-20000.For larger values we will take square root.
But for values like 1,2.. we wish to use the values directly, but the bubbles appear too small.

In *anyCharts* we can set min and max bubble sizes and also it relatively adjusts size.
Is there any way so that bubbles are visible in *highcharts.*

Comment: You would have to pre-process the data like you are doing with the square root. However, you may want to think about scaling/zooming your data. If the points can go to 0 to 20,000 that is a HUGE range to work over. Do you have an example output?

Comment: If your data range is that vast, you may want to have very small radii too